# Is there a way to implement my own CDN solution?

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, http-live-streaming, vod

I'm trying to build a VOD website and I can't afford a commercial CDN. Is it possible to build such an application without a CDN provider ? will I be able to buffer video segments without problems ? and  can I build a my own CDN alternative solution ?

Comment: If you have enough servers around the globe, sure

Comment: A CDN should save you money. They are generally cheaper than using your egress bandwidth. It will also be a better experience (less buffering, lower start up times) for your users.

Comment: @NullDev My app will be used basically in one region (France) that's why I asked the question !

Comment: Have you considered a peer-to-peer solution?  If you don't need live, you can use WebTorrent right out of the box.  For live, there is Peer5.